# Suspend Bitlocker programmatically?

Tags: .net, encryption

Is there a way to suspend Bitlocker for a drive programmatically from .NET?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: Found a better answer.

There's actually a WMI class called [Win32_EncryptableVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376483%28VS.85%29.aspx) that could probably be used to do this in a nice way. It has a `Decrypt` method that might be useful.

**Old answer below here**

In Windows 7, look at the tool `manage-bde.exe`, in Vista look at the script `manage-bde.wsf`.

Assuming that they can do what you want, you should be able to call them with the relevant parameters from your .Net app.

Comment: I don't need to decrypt, only suspend. I'll check if the WMI class has such a method.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I don't know BitLocker that much so wasn't sure exactly what you needed. Though thinking about it, maybe it's `DisableAutoUnlock` that you need?

Comment: PowerShell doesn't seem to know that Win32_ class.

Comment: @Andrew: Never used Powershell, in C# you need to add a reference to System.Management to use any of the WMI classes, could there be something similar you need to do? Otherwise, this blog post seems to have a sample for using it from Powershell: http://olddogsblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!C2DB05EEFA6C21A1!223.entry and here's a general WMI from powershell article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.05.powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I was planning to use this from C# but I usually try everything out in PS first.

Answer (score 1):

Command Line:

```
manage-bde -protectors -disable <drive letter>:
manage-bde -protectors -enable <drive letter>:
```

Powershell (WMI)

```
$bitlocker = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption -Class Win32_EncryptableVolume
$bitlocker.DisableKeyProtectors()
$bitlocker.EnableKeyProtectors()
```

C#

```
using System.Management // add reference
// ...

// disable Bitlocker
ManagementObject classInstance = new ManagementObject(@"root\cimv2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "Win32_EncryptableVolume.DriveLetter='C:'", null);
ManagementBaseObject outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("DisableKeyProtectors", null, null);

// enable Bitlocker
outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("EnableKeyProtectors", null, null);
```

Comment: Very good. Just a note: These commands require administrative access...and you can use volume guid instead of drive letter *if* it happens that you don't have the requisite drive mapped.

Answer (score 0):

The Win32EncryptableVolume WMI provider has a [DisableKeyProtectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376427.aspx) method that suspends BitLocker protection on a volume.